# How to change attribute status disabled="false" in product edit in admin in Magento2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

When I'm going to edit the product I'm not able to fill price and quantity in the product in admin of Magento 2.
You can see in below image attribute is disabled.
Can anyone tell me why attribute is disabled?

[image]

Comment: I think your product type is configurable so please check it

Comment: Yes, Issue solved. Thank you  so much Sania.